# Django Views filter objects by user from custom model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I've created custom user model, and i'm trying to filter data in views.py by that user.

The error i get is:

> 'SomeClassView' object has no attribute 'user'

My goal is to 'encapsulate' data for each user.

**user model:**

```
class CustomUserManger(BaseUserManager):

    use_in_migrations = True

    def create_user(self, email, username, password, **other_fields):
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, username=username, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password, **other_fields):
        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must be assigned to staff')
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must be assigned to superusers')
        return self.create_user(email, username, password, **other_fields)


class User(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = CustomUserManger()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

**Views:**

```
class SomeClassView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    user = SomeClass.user
    serializer_class = WagonSerializer
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, )

    @login_required
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return SomeClass.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Comment: remove the `user = SomeClass.user`...

Comment: I've removed, also removed decorator, but then none of data is displayed on frontend site.

Comment: Can you show me the code of `WagonSerializer` and `SomeClass`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i forgot that my react app doesn't put user to json, so in database user was null, that's why table was blank.